# Odoo app list in docker is not updated via odoo.conf file or when exec into the container

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo

I have a docker-compose file with two services: odoo:latest and postgres:13.
I try to update app list in debug mode http://localhost:8070/web?debug=1
but nothing happens.
odoo service has volumes section:

```
    `volumes:
     - ./extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons
     - data:/var/lib/odoo
     - ./config:/etc/odoo`
```

that corresponds to a this directory:

```
.
├── config
│   └── odoo.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
└── extra-addons
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __manifest__.py
```

Content of of oodo.conf file:

```
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
```

Content of **manifest.py**

```
{
'name': 'estate',
'depends': [
  'base_setup',    
 ],
 "installable": True,
 "application": True,
 "auto_install": False,
}
```

I also tried to update app list in the terminal.
When I exec in odoo service and issue this command:

`/usr/bin/odoo -p 8071 --db_host=172.17.0.2 --db_user=odoo --db_password=odoo -d odoo -u estate`

I get:

```
odoo: Odoo version 16.0-20221025 
odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf 
odoo: addons paths: ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons', '/var/lib/odoo/addons/16.0', '/mnt/extra-addons'] 
odoo: database: odoo@172.17.0.2:default 
odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/odoo", line 8, in 
    odoo.cli.main()
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 638, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "172.17.0.2", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: you could try the following repo: https://github.com/minhng92/odoo-16-docker-compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every module needs it's own directory.
As i see, you've put `__init__.py` and `__manifest__.py` inside `extra_addons` folder.

`extra_addons` should contain module folders, so correct structure should be:

```
.
├── config
│   └── odoo.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
└── extra-addons
    └── estate
      ├── __init__.py
      └── __manifest__.py
```

where **estate** is your module code (which for best practice should be the same as "name" key in manifest dictionary)

Furthermore, if you added ./extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons volume after you ran  your docker-compose, you should run it again.

This will only re-create your odoo container since postgres container has not changed, meaning you won't lose any data.